# Unable to scroll on website

Tags: html, css, scroll

On this website I am unable to scroll.

[www.Batan.io](http://batan.io/)

When I load the website for the first time the trackpad (mac) works fine but then the scroll function stops working. The sidebar works, I have changed the CSS position but to no avail.

Please will someone tell me why scrolling does not work on this website?

Thanks very much,

Thomas

```html
 $(function () {
        $('body').bind('mousewheel', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
            this.scrollTop = (scrollTop + ((event.deltaY * event.deltaFactor) * -1));
            //console.log(event.deltaY, event.deltaFactor, event.originalEvent.deltaMode, event.originalEvent.wheelDelta);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Is it your website? The scrolling has been disabled on line 111 of main.js `$('body').bind('mousewheel', function (event) {event.preventDefault();}`

Comment: it works on my machine (windows 10 Google Chrome)

Comment: @Paulie_D without knowledge of which part of the code is at fault, it would be very hard to comply with those otherwise very reasonable requirements.

Comment: You provide the *minimal* code to reproduce it....and that's what we diagnose. We don't need the whole codebase, just enough to demo the issue. Quite often you'll find that making the *minimal demo* will actually help you locate the issue.

Comment: @AndrewBone Thank you for your response. Can you see why the code below, would have any value? Can I just remove that code block to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There are likely a few issues with this code:

1. Unless setup otherwise, the`HTML` element will be the scrollable element
2. You are attempthing to access a jQuery function on a vanilla javascript`this`
3. You are not actually executing that function to get the value
4. You are not calling the funciton to set the desired value

   ```
   $(function() {
       // Change 'body' to 'html'
       $('html').bind('mousewheel', function(event) {
           event.preventDefault();

           var $window = $(this); // <--- Wrap the event target with a jQuery object
           var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop(); // <--- Call this function to return the result (use parens)

           /*
               Otherwise the reference on this line is to a function, not a value,
               and call the function (instead of setting a property)
           */
           $window.scrollTop(scrollTop + ((event.deltaY * event.deltaFactor) * -1));
       });
   });
   ```